# Regex select 3 group

Tags: regex

How can I select the third group of numbers using Regex.
With the following string.

```
21|2|964|Texto 02
```

I want to select only `964`.

I only managed to extract all the digit chunks with [`\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/xuX63L/1) regex.

Thanks.

Comment: is this how your string going to look all the time? meaning dd|d|ddd|text?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot split with `|` and get Item 3 from the resulting array, you may use

```
^(?:[^|]*\|){2}\K\d+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PB14V8/1).

Alternatively, use

```
^(?:[^|]*\|){2}(\d+)
```

and grab Group 1 value. See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PB14V8/2).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[^|]*\|){2}` - 2 sequences of:

  - `[^|]*` - any 0+ chars other than `|`
  - `\|` - a literal `|` symbol
- `\K` - a match reset operator discarding the text matched so far
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits.

Comment: I'm new to regex. I'm going to study your solution to learn. **Thanks.**

Comment: @RodrigoMartins: Note that regex is different across languages. Make sure you focus on the right flavor.